# Instantiating Separate Tensorflow Session for Each GPU

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to speed up Tensorflow inference by using multiple GPUs and instantiating a separate Session for each GPU.

I am using Tensorflow 1.7 and 2 Quadro GV100's for this.  The GV100's are device 0 and device 1, respectively.

My C++ code looks something like the following:

```
auto options0 = SessionOptions();
options0.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_visible_device_list("0");
NewSession(options0, &m_session0);

auto options1 = SessionOptions();
options1.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_visible_device_list("1");
NewSession(options1, &m_session1);
```

However, when I execute this code, I get the following error message:

name: Quadro GV100 major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.627
pciBusID: 0000:18:00.0
totalMemory: 31.87GiB freeMemory: 31.33GiB
2019-01-07 17:56:09.453901: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-01-07 17:56:10.196800: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-07 17:56:10.202994: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:917]      0
2019-01-07 17:56:10.206965: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:930] 0:   N
2019-01-07 17:56:10.211407: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 30421 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro GV100, pci bus id: 0000:18:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
17:56:11.099: Choosing GPU: 1
2019-01-07 17:56:11.280313: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro GV100 major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.627
pciBusID: 0000:3b:00.0
totalMemory: 31.87GiB freeMemory: 31.33GiB
2019-01-07 17:56:11.291274: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 1
2019-01-07 17:56:12.076807: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-07 17:56:12.082561: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:917]      1
2019-01-07 17:56:12.088587: I C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:930] 1:   N
2019-01-07 17:56:12.095142: F C:\tensorflow_1_7\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_id_manager.cc:45] **Check failed: cuda_gpu_id.value() == result.first->second (1 vs. 0)Mapping the same TfGpuId to a different CUDA GPU id. TfGpuId: 0 Existing mapped CUDA GPU id: 0 CUDA GPU id being tried to map to: 1**

My question is, what is the proper way to assign/dedicate a GPU to each Tensorflow session?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!